# Использование в TypeScript классов .Net

Tags: javascript, c++, .net, typescript, ecmascript-6

Есть идея иметь доступ из TypeScript к  методам и свойствам классов .Net.

У меня есть опыт вызова методов .Net объектов из натива https://habrahabr.ru/users/serginio1/topics/

И в частности [Кроссплатформенное использование классов .Net из неуправляемого кода. Или аналог IDispatch на Linux](https://habrahabr.ru/post/304482/)

Есть идея вызвать через [Native Client Messaging System](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/coding/message-system)

Там мы имеем взаимодействие JavaScript и натива через сообщения

В JavaScript мы можем подписаться на события

```
function handleMessage(message) {
  // In the example, we simply log the data that's received in the message.
  var logEl = document.getElementById('log');
  logEl.textContent += message.data;
}
```

И отправлять сообщения

```
var dictionary = {
  key:guid,
  MethodName: name,
  param_array: args
}
nacl_module.postMessage(dictionary);
```

На стороне натива

Можно принмать сообщения

```
virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var) {
  if (var.is_dictionary()) {
    pp::VarDictionary dictionary(var);
    // Use the dictionary
    pp::VarArray keys = dictionary.GetKeys();
    // ...
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Так и отправлять

```
pp::VarDictionary dictionary;
dictionary.Set(pp::Var("command"), pp::Var(next_command));
dictionary.Set(pp::Var("param_int"), pp::Var(123));
pp::VarArray an_array;
an_array.Set(0, pp::Var("string0"));
an_array.Set(1, pp::Var("string1"))
dictionary.Set(pp::Var("param_array"), an_array);
PostMessage(dictionary);
```

Все это можно сделать через Proxy

```
class NetWrapper{

    public currentCount: any;

    public static dictionary = {};

    public proxy: any;

    public static wm = new WeakMap(); // Слабые ссылки на объекты
    public static refArray = new Array<int>(); // ссылки на .Net объекты   
    constructor(private netRef:int) { this.SetProxy(); }


     private GetPromise(name: PropertyKey,args)
    {

        let key = Guid.newGuid();
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let item = new Item(resolve, args, name);
            this.dictionary[key] = item;

           var dictionary = {
           netRef:netRef,
           key:key,
           MethodName: name,
           param_array: args
         }
          nacl_module.postMessage(dictionary);
        });


        return promise;
    }


    private SetProxy(): void {

        let self=this;
        this.proxy = new Proxy({}, {

            get: function(rcvr: any, name: PropertyKey)
            {

               // Проблемы с определением, что свойство возвращает ссылку на метод
               // поэтому будем вызвать все как методы
               // if (этоСвойство)
               //     return self.GetPromise(name, []);

               return (...args) => {
                   return self.GetPromise(name,args)

                };


            }


        });
    }




// Пример вызова метода .Net

function handleMessage(message) {
  // In the example, we simply log the data that's received in the message.
  let data=message.data;
  let result=data.result;
  let item = <Item>this.dictionary[data.key];

  delete this.dictionary[key];

  if (data.resultIsObject)
   {

    let ref=<int>result;
    result=new NetWrapper(ref);
    refArray.push(ref);
    wm.set(result,ref);
  }

  item.resolve(result);

}
```

Так как в в JavaScript нет финализаторов, то можно использовать [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap)

То есть можно было бы выгрузить значения из wm и сравнить их с текущим массивом ссылок refArray. Если в WeakMap ссылок нет значит можно освободить ссылки и на стороне .Net

Но вроде как

> Из-за того, что ссылки являются слабыми, ключи WeakMap не перечисляемы
>   (то есть нет метода, который возвращает список ключей). Иначе список
>   бы зависел от состояния сбора мусора, представляя индетерминизм. Если
>   Вы хотите иметь список ключей, Вам следует поддерживать его
>   самостоятельно.

Использование такое

```
  let HttpClient=await NetWrap.GetType("System.Net.Http.HttpClient","System.Net.Http.dll");
     let HttpClientHandler = await NetWrap.GetType("System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler","System.Net.Http.dll");

    let client=await NetWrap.new(HttpClient);
    let responst= await (await client.GetStringAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh551745(v=vs.118).aspx")).Result();
 //Result вызываем как функцию
```

Можно для асинхронных методов result внутри Net сделать асинхронным

Буду рад любым советам. И может это никому и не нужно и не стоит вообще писать в стол?

Правда нашел ссылку на возможность финализатора https://www.npmjs.com/package/finalize

```
var finalize = require('finalize');
 
var obj = { x: 1337 };
finalize(obj, function () {
  console.log(this.x); // this will print '1337' 
});
global.gc();
// nothing will happen, var obj above holds obj alive 
obj = null;
global.gc();
// the previous line should trigger the callback above
```

Кроме того для интегации мне посрветовали [cef / JavaScriptIntegration](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration.md)

Можно и без асинхронности  вызова обычных методов обойтись.

При этом можно зарегистрировать различные обработчики для асинхронных методов, для событий

В итоге можно вызывать асинхронные методы например добавив кллючевое слово async, а для свойств можно использовать @ в начале свойства

```
let url= "https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh551745(v=vs.118).aspx");
let response= await client.async.GetStringAsync(url);
let response= client.GetStringAsync(url).@Result;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51694/discussion-on-question-by-serginio---typescript--net).

Comment: Похоже, что вы хорошо разбираетесь в  С# и решаете какие-то интересные задачи. Вот только вы делаете это в форме, не совсем подходящей для сайта Stack Overflow. Здесь принято задавать компактные, атомарные вопросы — строго одна проблема, для которой можно предложить (придумать, разработать) вполне конкретные решения. А вы как будто ведёте блог: задаёте сразу много вопросов и рассказываете о путях решения. Структура всего этого не вполне очевидна, поэтому КПД восприятия информации ниже.

Comment: Очень рекомендую вам перейти к формату «вопрос-ответ». Если нужна будет помощь со структурой, заголовками и т.п. — обращайтесь.

Comment: Так я и задаю вопрос. Мне нужно разобраться с кучей вопросов. Это и CEF и C++, это и TypeScript и es6. Например с CEF мне посоветовали на Rsdn. Я даже не знал с чего начать. Форумы молчат.

Comment: @Serginio во-первых, ваш вопрос непонятен никому кроме вас. В тексте вопроса даже вопросительных предложений нет, кроме риторических! Во-вторых, ваши ответы еще менее понятны чем ваш вопрос (и, насколько я могу судить, ответами не являются)

Comment: На RSDN кстати меня поняли. Вот здесь статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/320960/

Answer (score 1):

Сделал и работает на Angular 2 и TypeScript

```
let Net = NetObject.NetWrapper;

let del = NetObject.FlagDeleteObject;
//let SB = Net.Новый("System.Text.StringBuilder");
let StringBuilder = Net.Тип("System.Text.StringBuilder");
let SB = new StringBuilder();
this.AddComment("SB", SB);
var res = SB.Append("Первая строка");
res(del);

var ToStr = SB.ToString();
this.AddComment("Tostring=", ToStr);

SB.Capacity=40;

res = SB._Capacity;
this.AddComment("_Capacity=", res);
SB(del);
let Тестовый = Net.Тип("TestDllForCoreClr.Тестовый", "TestDllForCoreClr");
var TO = new Тестовый("Свойство из Конструктора");
 var resAsync = await TO.async.GetStringAsync();

this.ResultExecute.push(new ResTest("GetStringAsync", resAsync));

res = TO.ДженерикМетод(1, 2, 5);
this.AddComment("ДженерикМетод с выводом типов ", res);

let Int32 = Net.GetType("System.Int32");

res = TO.ДженерикМетод([Int32, Int32], 1, 2, 5);
this.AddComment("ДженерикМетод с аргeментами типов ", res);


var Dictionary2 = Net.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2", "System.Collections");
var DyctionaryIS = Net.GetGenericType(Dictionary2, "System.Int32", "System.String");
var D = new DyctionaryIS();

res = TO.ДженерикМетод2(D, 99, "Hello");

this.AddComment("ДженерикМетод2 с выводом типов ", res);

res = TO.ДженерикМетод2([Int32, "System.String"],D, 99, "Hello");
this.AddComment("ДженерикМетод2 с аргументами ", res);

var task = TO.GetStringAsync();
res = await Net.async.ReturnParam(task);


this.AddComment("выполнение полученной задачи асинхронно ", res);

var array = Net.GetNetArray(1, "Привет", 4.4);

for (let item of array)
    this.AddComment("Элемент ", item);




var EO = TO.ПолучитьExpandoObject();
this.AddComment("Свойство ExpandoObject Имя ",EO._Имя);
this.AddComment("Свойство ExpandoObject Число ", EO._Число);

var делегат = EO._ВСтроку;
this.AddComment("Результат вызова  делегата Встроку ", делегат());
this.AddComment("Результат вызова  как Метода ", EO.ВСтроку());

NetObject.DeleteNetObjets(Int32, task, D, DyctionaryIS, Dictionary2, TO, Тестовый, StringBuilder, array, EO, делегат);
this.AddComment("Количество элементов в хранилище ", Net.КоличествоЭлементовВХранилище());
this.AddComment("Первый удаленный ", Net.FirstDeleted());
```

Отличие от C# это 
Для получения свойства нужно добавить "_"

```
res = SB._Capacity;
```

Для вызова асинхронного метода нужно добавить ключевое слово async

```
var resAsync = await TO.async.GetStringAsync();
```

Для вызова дженерик метода, если нельзя вывести типы по параметрам то аргументы указываем в массиве

```
res = TO.ДженерикМетод2([Int32, "System.String"],D, 99, "Hello");
```

Поддержку событий и передачу объектов JS добавлю позже.
Буду рад любым предложениям и критике.
 
Какие примеры лучше дать для статьи?

Выложил в итоге статью с примерами [CEF, ES6, Angular 2, TypeScript использование классов .Net Core для расширения возможностей](https://habrahabr.ru/post/320960/)

И еще [CEF, Angular 2 использование событий классов .Net Core](https://habrahabr.ru/post/321452/)

И еще  [CEF, ES6, Angular 2, WebPack 2 .Net Core десктопное приложение без серверной части](https://habrahabr.ru/post/321898/)

Answer (score 0):

Кроме того на RSDN мне посоветовали [CEF удобное C++ API](http://rsdn.org/forum/flame.comp/6666288.1)

еще ссылка [cef / JavaScriptIntegration](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/JavaScriptIntegration.md)

Можно и без асинхронности вызова обычных методов обойтись.

При этом можно зарегистрировать различные обработчики для асинхронных методов, для событий

В итоге можно вызывать асинхронные методы например добавив кллючевое слово async, а для свойств можно использовать @ в начале свойства
Кроме того можно переопределить new

```
     let HttpClient= NetWrap.GetType("System.Net.Http.HttpClient","System.Net.Http.dll");
     let HttpClientHandler = NetWrap.GetType("System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler","System.Net.Http.dll");

    let client= new HttpClient(HttpClientHandler);

    let url= "https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh551745(v=vs.118).aspx");
    let response= await client.async.GetStringAsync(url);
    let response= client.GetStringAsync(url).@Result;
```

для ref параметров можно использовать класс обертку

```
class RefParam{
    isRefparam=true;
    constructor(public Value:any);
}
```

Кроме того можно реализовать  enumerate для доступа через

```
for(let prop in proxy)
```

Если кому интересно, то выложил статью [CEF,Es6,Angular 2,TypeScript использование классов .Net Core для расширения возможностей](https://habrahabr.ru/post/320960/)